# How to implement a continuously scanning multi-channel system in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, pulse, delay, hdl

I currently have a multi-channel system where each channel is receiving a pulse at different times. I want whichever channel receives its pulse first to act as the reference to then measure the time difference between the other channels.

I am trying to implement this in Verilog and I do not know how to code the channels (or inputs) so that they are continuously scanning and waiting for their pulses. I need my design to work this way since I do not have prior knowledge of which channel will receive its pulse first.

Comment: It's trickier than you think. "First" is a relative term, and you need to decide what it means relative to some common event. For example, you could define it as "first after a gap of x seconds without any pulses" or "first after a reset signal". Furthermore, if all of the pulses are asynchronous with respect to each other, there will always be some tiny ambiguity as to which one was "first" if they occur nearly simultaneously.

Comment: @DaveTweed I see what you mean. I think for my application I would need to know the first signal after a reset.

Comment: Does it need to scan? Or can it just watch all channels simultaneously?

Comment: @DKNguyen It doesn't need to "scan" it just needs to detect which channel receives its pulse first

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach would be to have a free-running counter that measures time in units of its clock period. Each channel, when it receives a pulse, captures the value of the counter into a register. The counter must be big enough so that it doesn't overflow in the expected total time between the first and last pulses. Once all of the channels have triggered, you just need to sort the captured values into ascending order and take the differences between adjacent values.

A variation on this would be to feed the counter value into a FIFO along with flags for all of the signal channels, and trigger a FIFO write whenever any channel gets a pulse. Now the timestamps are already sorted, so the differences are easy to compute, and you can see what order the channels fired in by examining the flags.

I would start with something like this. Note that this just covers capturing the data; doing something useful with it is up to you.

```
module pulse_timestamp (
  input   [7:0] channel,
  input         clock,
  input         reset
);

  /* Total elapsed time from last reset.
   */
  reg    [31:0] time;
  always @(posedge clock) time <= reset ? 0 : time + 1;

  /* Bring the asynchronous channel signals into our clock domain and do
   * rising-edge detection on them. Note that since all channels experience
   * the same delay through this process, it doesn't affect the relative time
   * measurements.
   */
  reg     [7:0] channel_a;
  reg     [7:0] channel_b;
  reg     [7:0] channel_c;
  reg     [7:0] rising_edge;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    channel_a <= channel;
    channel_b <= channel_a;
    channel_c <= channel_b;
    rising_edge <= channel_b & ~channel_c;
  end

  /* Write the timestamps and channel flags into a FIFO
   */
  reg     [3:0] wr_addr;
  reg    [39:0] fifo [0:15];
  wire    wr_enable = |rising_edge;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) wr_addr <= 0;
    if (wr_enable) begin
      fifo[wr_addr] <= {rising_edge, time};
      wr_addr <= wr_addr + 1;
    end
  end

  /* NOTE: reading out the fifo and doing something with the information
   * is left as an exercise for the reader.
   */

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Code just a single input capture block that records the value of a counter/timer input upon an incoming pulse and also sends an output trigger when it does so. Then generate a bunch of them and connet their time base input to a master timer block (that you also write) that is in turn triggerable by all the capture blocks via ORing, but only once (non-retriggerable). Then if you want to later change it to scan, you can re-use all those blocks. Think in terms of blocks, not one massive do-all. Scanning is sequential and weird issues due to incomplete thinking can crop up since FPGAs aren't well suited for software-like loops. Get a simpler simultaneous design working first.

You can work out the details of when master timer's non-retriggerability can be overridden and reset to zero and idle based on your system criteria (maybe after all channels have recorded something if you know something should be coming in on every channel). Up to you. Don't forget your synchronization flip flops if the input is coming from a different clock domain that your FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

You are in essence creating a a logic analyzer with a fixed trigger condition: any input making a 0-to-1 transition. Trigger on that, store successive samples with time stamps in a FIFO, then measure the time between changes of state, noting what bits have changed between samples. Then you have a list of arrival times and bits.

If you're using an FPGA that has a SERDES module, you could use this to get a fine-grained sampling of the input. As you think about your coding, consider how this hardware could be used to make your system higher performance.